Formula to have value changed from HH:MM:SS to MM:SS
This is a bit of a stupid situation, but I am at a loss for what to do. My company recently switched systems which has caused reporting to change slightly. There is a certain figure that we input into a separate report, but the figure is formatted differently in the new system. To be fair, I think the new system is the correct way and we will be adjusting the report in the future, but the system change was mid-month so I need to find a workaround to make it work in the meantime. The report is used by supervisors in my company and there is conditional formatting based on the values in that report which is currently not working correctly with the new formatting. We would have to change this document's formatting which would be hard to do with 50+ supervisors. Here is the situation:
The figure is an average handle time figure. It was formatted in the previous report like this:
Shows in the cell as: 8:15 (h:mm). Ill include pictures below. In the formula bar, it shows as 8:15:00 AM. So it is recognizing what is actually minutes as hours but it works because that's how it comes from the source.
The new report does it properly as: 00:08:15 (HH:MM:SS) and shows the same in the formula bar.
Essentially, what I am looking for is some way to make the 00:08:15 from the new report show the same way as the old report. I feel like there must be a formula or something out there but I couldn't find one when I looked online. I can't just change the formatting of the cell because the actual value is still the same and still affects the end document that the data goes into. Changing the format doesn't actually change how the data looks in the cell anyway. Any help is GREATLY appreciated and again, the new report is definitely the correct way and it will be fixed in the future.
New report

Old report


Multiply it by 60? or just format the cells MM:SS?

As @BigBen suggested, is it feasible to change the time format for the range in new reports? I wonder the whether the old one uses "[m]:ss;@" - could you try?

=TEXT(H4,"MM:SS")
